# Debugging using Java source code

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, debugging, jviewport

Is there a way to include whole Java source code into an eclipse project so the program is easier to debbug (e.g. by inserting println in methods you otherwise couldn't insert anything)?

I have a bug in my code. But to better understand why the bug in my code appears, I'd like to see what intermediate results in some system method (on which use the bug occurs) are.

For example, I'd like to know what JViewPort.scrollRectToVisible() exactly does and how my input behaves in it by printing out some intermediate results that occur in the method itself.

**EDIT:**

Instead of using JRE System Library X, I want to add the source code from JDK as if I had written the code myself. I want to be able to edit any System class just as I am able to edit any class I created myself. I want editable .java files, not packed .jars...

Comment: This question confuses me. You're not talking about logging, are you?

Comment: DO you mean debugging into code you didn't write?  If you're in eclipse you already have the source of _your_ code available to set breakpoints and single-step.

Comment: You can set breakpoints and run the code in debug mode in Eclipse, so you are confusing everyone with your question.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I think it's clear now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the library code, but you can view it by using [de-compiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/). The max you can do is this. Now if you change any code in the libraries which you reached via the de-compiler, you would find an error stating "**the integrity of the .jar package has changed which is not allowed**"

Comment: But couldn't I ommit the Java System Libaray from the project and insteda just copy C:\Program Files\Java\Java 7\src folder to my projects src folder?

Comment: @Karlovsky120 Even if you copy those source files, you would not get the whole source code. Atleast JDK 6 had some restrained files that were available as binary files alone. A de-compiler would go a long way in displaying the code responsible.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add the 3rd-party library to your Eclipse workspace as an project.  (How you would do that depends on the code you are dealing with.)  Once you have done that, you can hack your copy of the library to add trace prints etcetera.

A better alternative is to simply attach the source code for the 3rd-party library so that the debugger can show you source as you step through the code, set breakpoints,.  Then use "advanced breakpoint" techniques instead of trace prints; e.g. http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html#advanced

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse have built-in support for what you wanna do.

All you have to do is set breakpoint and execute application in debugging mode.

[image: Eclipse Debugging Icons]

You  can use these icons in Eclipse debugging perspective.

Follow along [Eclipse Debugging Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html) for details.